# Programming OS on old flip phone LG B460

Tags: lg

I have an LG true flip phone 
model number:LG B460
Software Version: B46010d

I want to figure out what development environment this phone's OS was written in and what language was used.

I'm working on a project where I have to change the length of time the phone vibrates for when a message is received and possibly more.

Does anyone know how to work with mobile phone software this old?

Thanks

Comment: I found some open source software for LG phones at  http://opensource.lge.com/osList/list?m=Mc001&s=Sc002. You can perform a search for LGB460 using CNTRL+F. I dont know how to use or edit this software though if anyone has any idea

Answer (score 1):

According to LG the OS is ["proprietary"](https://www.lg.com/us/support/products/documents/LG%20TRUE%20B460%20Spec%20Sheet%20(English).pdf).

Given that, development on this kind of devices was usually done in embedded Java or some other horrible development platform.

Depending on the actual underlying hardware development on these often was only done on devices with a debugging port exposed. In production hardware it was usually not soldered-in.

Also it may be, that even if you would access the debugging port and correctly download the firmware, you wouldn't be able to edit it due to code signing.

If your project is an intro to reverse-engineering embedded platforms then go ahead, but if I was in your shoes I would drop the project for something more accessible.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Is there an LGB460 malware that can be used to complete this task? How can I access this sort of sotware

Comment: Magic 8ball says "no". My best guess - you'll have to write your own given that it's a small(ish) proprietary OS on a feature phone released in 2014, so long after mass smartphone adoption. Who would care to exploit it? What's the potential payoff for hacking it? It can have some glaring vulnerabilities if the OS was not updateable but see earlier points.

Comment: How about this, is there a way to pull the firmware off a phone like this and save it on my hard drive? or to install firmware onto the phone from my hard drive?

Comment: All I found were sketchy apps for unlocking and a similarly sketchy firmware puller (meant rather for Android phones) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1073827

Comment: Possibly there's a hidden service menu allowing for diagnostics and using the USB port but I couldn't find anything on it either. It's a closed-source flip-phone. Chances of getting the firmware are pretty much non-existent. It's possible that the os is baked-in to a SoC custom-made for this device. Hard to tell without tearing it apart.